# How to use reader.GetDecimal() for a column in a separate table?

Tags: c#, desktop-application, sqlcommand

I have two tables in my database: Students, and accounts. In my application, I am trying read data from multiple tables using reader.GetDecimal() method and having trouble getting data from the second table.

Is it possible to do this using the GetDecimal method? Or do I need to add to one of the queries to get what I need from the **Accounts** table?

**Database Tables:**

Accounts

[image: Accounts]

Student
[image: Student]

**Code:**

```
            //Query Student table for bAlertSetup
            SqlCeCommand AlertQuery = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * from Students AND Accounts", conn);
            reader = AlertQuery.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                bSinglePersonAlertSetup = reader.GetBoolean(5);

                if (bSinglePersonAlertSetup == true)
                {
                    int AccountID = reader.GetInt32(7);
                    decimal Threshold = reader.GetDecimal(6);
                    //decimal Total = get decimal from the accounts table where accountID (in the accounts table) = AlertAccountID

                    //See if Students account is below the defined threshold
                    if (Total < Threshold)
                    { 
                        StudentEmailAddress = reader.GetString(3);

                        if (StudentEmailAddress != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(StudentEmailAddress);
                            mail.To.Add(StudentEmailAddress);

                            //Update bAlertSetup
                            SqlCeCommand UpdateBool = new SqlCeCommand("UPDATE Students set bSendAlert = 0 WHERE UserId = @ID");
                            UpdateBool.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", reader.GetInt32(0));
                            UpdateBool.Connection = conn;
                            UpdateBool.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }     
                }
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the new query I am using that I believe joins the two tables correctly with the columns needed. Now, how do I get the index of each column to use in the GetDecimal() Method?

```
SqlCeCommand AlertQuery = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT st.bAlertSetup, st.AccountThreshold, st.AlertAccountID, acc.AccountID, acc.AccountTotal FROM Students st INNER JOIN Accounts acc ON st.AlertAccountID = acc.AccountID", conn);
```

Comment: Try this:  read.GetDecimal(6).ToString().

Comment: You need to edit your query here to get the column from second table as well.

Comment: I believe that part currently works correctly how it is. The problem I am having is getting the corresponding "AccountID" and "AccountTotal" from the Accounts table.

Comment: Can that be done by changing this line: SqlCeCommand AlertQuery = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * from Students AND Accounts", conn); Or do I need a whole new query?

Comment: Don't you have to perform an INNER JOIN between the two tables? Essentially you need SELECT Accounts.* FROM Accounts
INNER JOIN Student ON Accounts.StudentID = Student.UserId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SqlCeCommand AlertQuery = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT S.*,A.AccountTotal from Students S Inner Join Accounts A ON S.AlertAccountID = A.AccountID");
```

Make sure to execute the query in sql and know the index of each column to provide the correct index, **or replace S.* by S.*[FieldName]* for each field comma seperated and that the order of your columns will be always preserved in the query**.

Comment: If I define each column I want in the query such as S.AccountThreshold, S.AlertAccountID. Will the index I use for the GetDeimal() method correspond to the order I list it in the query? So I would use GetDecimal(0) to find AccountThreshold?

Comment: Exactly, If S.AccountThreshold comes first in your query, then it is at index 0

Answer (score 1):

You should properly join the two tables in your query, and only select the individual columns you need.  So your query might be something like below...

```
SELECT st.UserID, st.FirstName, st.LastName, acc.AccountName, acc.AccountTotal
FROM Student st
JOIN Accounts acc
ON st.AlertAccountID = acc.AccountID
```

You could get the AccountTotal then by name, like this...

```
decimal total = reader.GetDecimal("AccountTotal");
```

Comment: I get a cannot convert string to int error when compiling. Is there a way to get the index in the table from the column name?

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatablereader.getdecimal(v=vs.90).aspx

You can use this

```
decimal total = reader.GetDecimal(2); //index column name
```

hope will help you